# Unable to create Global region using Spring Data Geode/Gemfire

Tags: spring, spring-boot, geode, spring-data-gemfire

From spring data geode/gemfire, can we create Regions on the cluster ? Currently it is creating local cache region but any configuration being done either in ClientCache mode or ServerCache mode, doesn't have any impact on the Cluster server.

But using gfsh commands if we create a REPLICATE Region then the connectivity works fine. Is that the only way to create a REPLICATE
region in Gemfire/Geode cluster ?

Next, there are many documentation which refers to Region with GLOBAL scope but again in gfsh there is no way to create a Region with Scope GLOBAL, nor I could locate any configuration via Spring data geode.

Do we have any additional information on this ?

Regards,
Malaya

Searched the Geode/Gemfire documentation regarding any commannds but couldn't find any.

Tried to adapt the spring data geode/gemfire but even there also there is no option of GLOBAL region creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Spring Data for Apache Geode* (SDG) does support pushing configuration metadata for Apache Geode *Regions* (and other Apache Geode objects, e.g. *Indexes*) to the cluster of servers using the SDG [Cluster Configuration Push](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-cluster) feature. However, this feature currently only pushes the Region "name" and `DataPolicy` type ([Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/DataPolicy.html)) to the servers from the client.

Additionally, "*Cluster Configuration Push*" only applies when your Spring [Boot] Data application is an Apache Geode `ClientCache`. If the application is a peer `Cache`, then this feature does **not** apply.

> NOTE: *Spring Boot for Apache Geode* (SBDG) applies additional features on top of SDG's *Cluster Configuration Push* feature. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-configuration-declarative-annotations-productivity-enableclusteraware). Again, this applies to clients only.

AFAIR, [`Scope.GLOBAL`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Scope.html#GLOBAL) Regions only applies to [`REPLICATE`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/DataPolicy.html#REPLICATE) Regions, first of all. That is, you cannot create a "GLOBAL" `PARTITION` Region. See [Apache Geode docs](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/developing/region_options/storage_distribution_options.html) for further details on `Scope` along with other Region distribution configuration attributes.

Assuming your Spring [Boot] Data for Apache Geode application were a peer `Cache` instance, then you can configure your `REPLICATE` Regions with a "GLOBAL" `Scope` as follows:

```java
// Alternatively, you can use @CacheServerApplication
@PeerCacheApplication(name = "MySpringGeodeServer")
class MySpringDataGeodeApplication {

  @Bean("MyRegion")
  ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean myReplicateRegion(GemFireCache cache) {

    ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean region = new ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean();

    region.setCache(cache);
    region.setScope(Scope.GLOBAL);

    return region;
  }
}
```

However, keep in mind this peer `Cache`, Spring-configured server application is NOT going to push the configuration to other servers in the cluster.

If you are using SDG [Annotation-based configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-regions) to (dynamically & conveniently) create Regions in your Spring peer `Cache` application, for example: using either [`@EnableEntityDefinedRegions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableEntityDefinedRegions.html) or perhaps [`@EnableCachingDefinedRegions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnableCachingDefinedRegions.html), then you will need to additionally rely on 1 or more `RegionConfigurer` bean definitions (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-configurers)) to customize the configuration of individual Regions as the Annotation-based support does not enable fine-grained Region configuration customization of this nature (e.g. `Scope` on `REPLICATE` Regions).

This might look something like the following.

Given a persistent entity:

```java
@Region("Customers")
class Customer { 
  // ...
}
```

Then:

```java
@CacheServerApplication(name = "MySpringGeodeServer")
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(
  basePackageClasses = Customer.class,
  serverRegionShortcut = RegionShortcut.REPLICATE
)
class MySpringDataGeodeApplication {

  @Bean
  RegionConfigurer customerRegionConfigurer() {

    return new RegionConfigurer() {

      @Override
      public void configure(String beanName, PeerRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> region) {

        if ("Customers".equals(beanName)) {
          ((ReplicatedRegionFactoryBean) region).setScope(Scope.GLOBAL);
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

> NOTE: Alternatively, if you need such fine-grained control over Region (bean) configuration like this, then you should simply use the Java-based configuration rather than Annotations, anyway. Annotation-based configuration is primarily provided for convenience; it is not a 1-size fits all by any means.

Technically, you could also annotate your persistent entity classes (e.g. `Customer`) with 1 of the Region type-specific mapping annotations ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/annotation/package-frame.html)), rather than simply the generic `@Region` mapping annotation, as well, such as with [`@ReplicateRegion`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/annotation/ReplicateRegion.html). This allows you to do things like:

```java
@ReplicateRegion(name = "Customers", scope = Scope.GLOBAL)
class Customer {
  // ...
}
```

Still, I generally prefer users to simply use the generic `@Region` mapping annotation, and again, if they need to do low-level configuration of Regions (like setting "`Scope`" on a `REPLICATE` Region) then simply use Java-based configuration as the opening example demonstrated.

Still, keep in mind, none of this is shared across the other servers inside the same cluster. Spring peer `Cache` applications do NOT push configuration metadata to other servers at all, and never will. This is sort of the point of using Apache Geode's [Cluster Configuration Service](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_persist.html) anyhow.

> NOTE: SDG peer `Cache` applications can be enabled (**disabled by default**) to inherit configuration from an existing cluster using Apache Geode's Cluster Configuration Service. For instance, see the `useClusterConfiguration` attribute ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/PeerCacheApplication.html#useClusterConfiguration--)) on the `PeerCacheApplication` annotation. There are strong reasons why SDG disabled this peer/server-side feature by default.

Upon reviewing [this](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863) and [this](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/alter.html#topic_E74ED23CB60342538B2175C326E7D758) (not that `Scope` is something you can "alter" on a Region after the fact anyway), you are CORRECT, when using *Gfsh*, you cannot create a `GLOBAL` Scoped `REPLICATE` Region in the cluster, :(

In general, keep in mind that anything that is possible to do with Apache Geode's [API](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/index.html), you can definitely do with *Spring (Boot/Data) for Apache Geode* and then some.

This is due in large part because SDG was built on Apache Geode's API and not some tool, like *Gfsh*.

Comment: Thank you John for the response. I will retry with above details and update on the outcome.

Comment: I tried to create a region as a ClientCache but it was not creating anything in the server side. 

You can find the example here: https://github.com/nayakmk/geode-client

I am running geode following https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.7.x/reference/html5/#geode-docker

Comment: See here: https://github.com/jxblum/geode-client/tree/feedback#feedback

Comment: Then compare this https://github.com/jxblum/geode-client/tree/feedback/src with this https://github.com/jxblum/geode-client/tree/spring-boot/src and learn why Spring Boot for Apache Geode (SBDG) is better than simply using Spring Boot with Spring Data Geode.

Comment: When testing, you should really start with the simplest thing that could possibly work before throwing in the kitchen sink at the start... Spring-based Web application + Spring Cloud + Docker, etc, etc... too much, especially when you started off on the wrong foot in the first place. Start as simple as possible; make it work first, then add to it step by step while trying to keep the example running correctly.

Comment: Just that I am not using SBDG due to the fact that lt will be getting sunset and not getting a 2.0 version, as per our earlier communications.

Comment: I was merely following the above explanation to get the region creation working but seems I mixed Peer Cache and Client Cache configuration. I will go through the example and update if I am able to get it working.

Comment: Hi Malaya- Just checking in with you again to make sure you are able to make forward progress. Let me know when you know, no rush.

Comment: Additionally, I wanted to clarify 1 bit of information in regards to SBDG, that essentially all the Spring projects for Apache Geode are coming to an end, at some point in the future. This includes NOT only Spring Boot for Apache Geode, but also Spring Data, Spring Session and Spring Test for Apache Geode as well. Again, specifically from the Spring Data for Apache Geode (SDG) GitHub project page itself: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode#notice

Comment: Again all the projects are here: SDG - https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-geode, STDG - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-data-geode, SSDG - https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-data-geode, and SBDG - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode. NOTE: not all of the projects [SDG, STDG, SSDG and SBDG] had project pages on spring.io. SBDG is the culmination of all my work from SDG to STDG to SSDG, building and pulling all of these projects together as 1, using Spring Boot's programming model.

Comment: Finally, SDG, STDG, SSDG and SBDG support will roughly all follow the same support timeline, which breaks down into OSS support and commercial support.  For example, see the SDG support tab for details: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-geode#support. For instance, SDG 2.7 OSS support ends on May of 2023 with extended commercial support up to Sept. 2024. After 9/2024. SDG will be no more as 2.7 is the last release of Spring Data for Apache Geode. SDG `3.0` did NOT happen either. It's not only SBDG.

Comment: Similarly, SBDG `2.0` was based on Spring Boot `3.0`. However, since SBDG `2.0` did not happen, and could not happend because SBDG was based on SDG `3.0`, which was not released, then SBDG `1.7`, based on Spring Boot `2.7`, is the last release in SBDG. Spring Boot `2.7` is also the last Spring Boot release in the `2.x` release line.  As such, SBDG `1.7` will following Spring Boot's `2.7` OSS/commercial support timelines: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support Make sense? So, for the time being, you can use SBDG if you are using SDG anyway, since all Spring projects for Geode are ending

Comment: FYI: These new Spring bits for VMware GemFire will be the replacement of the Spring for Apache Geode bits: https://docs.vmware.com/en/Spring-Boot-for-VMware-GemFire/index.html All of the new/alt things build on the things I already built, but now geared towards VMware GemFire in particular.

Comment: I was able to validate the example with the changes you have done as part of both the feedback branch and spring boot branch. In both the cases, I was getting a replicated region in Cluster with Scope as Distributed ACK. Now coming to the alternate approach: When I am trying the branch feedback with the commented lines uncommented ` ` and removing @EnableEntityDefinedRegions, I am getting an error that, Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: operation is not supported on a client cache

Comment: Coming back to the reason why the code in my branch was in that state:

1. My scenario doesn't involve a peer cache application.
2. I wasn't aware of ReplicatedRegion annotation till it was mentioned above but that annotation did support Scope attributed which `@Region` annotation was not, hence the assumption that it might be the way to define `@EntityDefinedRegions` with Scope GLOBAL.